# Pistache openapi generator not mapping schema

Tags: c++, openapi-generator-cli

I'm using the pistache server generator to generate a model.
I have a schemaMapping such as :

```
MyObject1: org::openapi::model::MyObject2
```

When the generator runs MyObject1 is NOT created as expected. However, the endpoint still uses it. It includes MyObject1.h and all the arguments are still MyObject1.

I expected the endpoint to use MyObject2?

Is that a bug? Is there a way to force usage of MyObject2 ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get what I wanted by setting schemaMapping, typeMapping, and importMapping like this:

```
schemaMappings:
  MyObject1: MyObj
importMappings:
  MyObject1: MyObj
typeMappings:
  MyObject1: MyObj
```

The schemaMapping controls if the object will be created or not. The importMapping controls the include file, and the typeMapping controls the type of the arguments.